# Change Authentication of Eureka Client on JHipster

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, jhipster, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using JHipster.

I have 3 different Apps.
JHipster Registry instance
JHipster Gateway instance
JHipster Microservice instance

Whenever I change the following I get a 401 during startup of the Gateway and Microservice instances.

Change the Eureka client config:

```
eureka:
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
    client:
        enabled: true
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Change the Eureka Server Config

```
security:
    user:
        name: admin
        password: <better password>
        role: USER,ADMIN
```

changing admin:admin to admin:

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the JHipster Registry is a Spring Cloud Server as well. So when you change your password, you should also apply

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://admin:betterpass@localhost:8761/config
```

in your bootstrap-dev.yml (or bootstrap-prod, if you run this in production or in docker) of your client application, or by passing it via environment vars like

```
SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=...
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer if you include a note that says modify this in the bootstrap-dev.yml file of your client app.

Comment: i added some more precise notes